# Create vs. New - Powershell approved verbs

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to abide as strictly as possible to Microsoft's Powershell development guidelines and best practices but I am getting warnings on importing a custom module:

```
WARNING: The names of some imported commands from the module 'F5Helper' include unapproved verbs that might make them less discoverable.
To find the commands with unapproved verbs, run the Import-Module command again with the Verbose parameter. For a list of approved verbs, type Get-Verb.

VERBOSE: The 'Create-iRule' command in the F5Helper' module was imported, but because its name does not include an approved verb, it might be difficult to find.
The suggested alternative verbs are "New".
VERBOSE: Importing function 'Create-iRule'.
```

I couldn't find information anywhere else but maybe someone here can tell me why is it that the word New should be used over the word Create?

In my case, the function 'Create-iRule' does just that, it creates an iRule.

I know someone is bound to post an answer stating: "But you *are* creating a '*New-iRule*' so that should be the name of the function!"
To those people, I'll remind you that **New isn't a verb, whereas Create is**.

So why is New on the list of approved verbs and Create outputs a warning?

[Approved Verbs for Windows PowerShell Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands)

Comment: +1 for pointing out that "new" is not, in fact a verb! Reminds me of a famous quote from another industry: _'chicken' should not be used as an adjective._ (as in chicken-fried steak). :-)

Comment: So that's why I always accidentally write Create-Item and then have to change it to New-Item. Because 'new' is not a verb. It does annoy me this. We can be called pedantic, but scripters have to be to build good scripts. There's nothing more pedantic than a computer.

Comment: In English, any noun can be verbed.  Admittedly "now" isn't a noun either.  But maybe any word can be verbed.

Comment: 'Verbed' is my favourite noun that's been verbed. I love verbing nouns.

Comment: Microsoft has added commentary on the use of New as a verb (English site) and expanded on how to choose a Verb. I updated the link in the OP question to go to the updated location of the original page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have a definitive source for this, so it is speculation, but `New` and `Add` are valid verbs that existed first, and seem (I think) to cover any situation where you might use `Create`.

I know that when they add new verbs they try to avoid overlap with existing verbs.

From the [Soliciting New Verbs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/04/22/soliciting-new-verbs.aspx) post from the [Windows PowerShell Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/):

> To provide some context, here are the things we think about when
>   deciding whether to add a new verb:
>
> - Little or no overlap with existing approved verbs
> - Broadly applicable to multiple technologies - must be domain agnostic
> - Used consistently with similar meaning across multiple contexts
> - Pairing with an opposite is good, but not required

Comment: I can see where they are coming from but in my specific example, the verb 'add' isn't applicable. In fact, I do have another function in the module called 'Add-iRule' that imports without issue. I'm still wondering why 'New' is an accepted verb though, how can you use 'New' as a verb? Of course, this is just pedantism, I could just keep my mouth shut about it if there's no real reasoning behind it

Comment: More speculation...perhaps `New` is just a shortened form of `CreateNew`?

Comment: I'm thinking it's more like the `new` keyword in languages such as C++, C#, and Visual Basic.

Answer (score 5):

According to Microsoft:

> PowerShell uses the term verb to describe a word that implies an action even if that word is not a standard verb in the English language. For example, the term New is a valid PowerShell verb name because it implies an action even though it is not a verb in the English language.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is probably deserving of a ["Microspeak" article from Raymond Chen](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/tag/microspeak) but the New- "verb" probably is directly related to the phrase "newing up a variable"...

Comment: Newing up a variable? Sounds like something you made up on the spot

Answer (score 0):

It just makes it easier to learn with a limited number of verbs.  I don't have any with the create verb:

```
 Get-Command -verb create
```